# Should we wait till the access token expire before we get refresh token?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Or can I just ask for it right away?

Say after getting my first refresh token I want to test whether I can get refresh token or not.

Also will refresh token be the same? Does it change every time I "refresh"?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the spec that limits you to only using the refresh token to get a new access token. If the implementation you're using follows spec, and there's no other issues, you should be able to ask for it right away.

In practice, this is rarely needed as it costs more time to do the communication and authentication with the authorization server.

The refresh token can change when you use it to get another access token or it can remain the same.

The spec states that if a new refresh token is *not* returned along with the new access token, it's assumed that the old refresh token is to be used, and so hasn't changed.

Some might only want to give a single refresh token with the initial acccess token, and once that expires, you need to restart the process with reauthenticating and authorizing the end-user.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5

Comment: So it varies between implementation? Can anyone vouch for this?

Comment: That part shouldn't vary if the OAuth 2.0 spec is followed correctly.